# Partitioning for Ubuntu -- question about partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, swap

So the question title wasn't very specific, but I couldn't really think of what to call this.

My computer came with Windows 10, and I'm trying to run Ubuntu alongside it because of some of its capabilities, and I'm stuck at partitioning. I don't fully understand what all the partitions are for:

[image: Current Partitions]

Edit: So the picture didn't come out clear:

---

In order: Device, Type, Size, Used, System

```
/dev/sda1, ntfs, 104 MB, 32 MB, Windows 10(loader)

/dev/sda2, ntfs, 400000 MB, 170205 MB, N/a

unusable, 90999 MB, N/a, N/a

/dev/sda3, ntfs, 471 MB, 337 MB, N/a

/dev/sda4, ntfs, 8529 MB, 7493 MB, Windows Recovery Environment(loader)
```

---

So is it safe to delete `sda3` (with 471 MB) or is there something I need to do to make the unusable partition available for Ubuntu to be installed onto?

I experimented with removing `sda3` and changed unusable to `ext3`, which worked, but it said I needed a swap area. I reverted it back to the way it's listed.

Comment: That screenshot is way too small. Can you make it larger?

Comment: Preferably take a better picture with another camera. As it is now, it's useless because of the bad quality.

Comment: First, using windows, see if the windows is installed using UEFI as described here: http://superuser.com/questions/946868/how-to-test-whether-windows-10-was-installed-with-uefi and if the disk has GPT or MBR partition table as described here: http://www.howtogeek.com/245610/how-to-check-if-a-disk-uses-gpt-or-mbr-and-how-to-convert-between-the-two/.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the problem. The partitions that you are seeing here are of NTFS format which is compatible with windows. For ubuntu, this wont work. You will have to create an EXT4 partition. You will get this option during installation. For linux systems it is necessary to create a swap partition for better performance. The biggest problem for you is the limit to the number of partitions you can have in one hard drive, which is 4. So layout is:

1st partition - NTFS for windows

2nd partition - EXT4 for ubuntu

3rd partition - swap area

In your case, you can reformat your unusable space as ext4 for ubuntu. I cant see which of your partition has windows, most probably /dev/sda2. If thats the case then split your unusable space into an ext4 partition and a swap partition. Also while installing boot loader for Ubuntu, make sure you overwrite Windows bootloader which is /dev/sda1. Windows bootloaders create a lot of problems. Also can you tell me if your system has UEFI boot enabled or not? You can check this from bios menu. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I didn't think you saw this because of your comment about picture resolution, so here this is. I was wondering if it was safe to delete sda3 even though it has 337 MB of data on it, because sda4 is already taken by Windows Recovery Environment. You also asked about UEFI boot, but I couldn't find out because one of the most frustrating things about the computer in question is the bios menu only flashes for like a millisecond, if at all, it jumps immediately into launching windows.

Comment: And sorry in advance, it doesn't let making new lines in a comment...

In order: Device, Type, Size, Used, System:    
/dev/sda1, ntfs, 104 MB, 32 MB, Windows 10(loader)

/dev/sda2, ntfs, 400000 MB, 170205 MB, N/a

unusable, 90999 MB, N/a, N/a

/dev/sda3, ntfs, 471 MB, 337 MB, N/a

/dev/sda4, ntfs, 8529 MB, 7493 MB, Windows Recovery Environment(loader)

Comment: Do one thing. Boot into windows and check the size of the OS drive/partition, the one in which windows is installed. As because there are two unknown partition - /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3 any one of them can contain windows os. I dont know why diskpart app coudnt figure that out. It should have in the first place. As I said Its highly likely that Windows os is in /dev/sda2 and you can delete /dev/sda3, but just confirm it by checking the size of the drive and proceed accordingly. If the size matches with sda2 then remove sda3.

Comment: I booted into windows, it says the os is on sda2, and it says sda3 is a recovery drive

Comment: it also seems like whatever windows doesn't have a swap partition now so if I don't restart daily Ill run out of ram... I could be wrong, but I just recently ran out of memory and that never happens

Comment: so if OS is on sda2, then go on and remove sda3. You dont have to worry about anything. Windows os doesnt need any swap partition. And if you want to add extra memory for windows to run smoothly, create virtual memory in windows

Comment: Ill try it, but worst comes to worst is there a way to reset the partitions to what it was before or would I have to do that manually?

Comment: I dont think there is any way to "reset" partitions. All you can do is create partitions manually